# C++ logging libraries

Tags: c++, logging

I'm trying to find good C++ library, which supports this features:
so this is the task

1. Free license (Apache, MIT, LGPL which I can use for commercial).
2. Accept several severity levels (Like error, notice, info etc).
3. Support to rollback the log files if they reach a size or a time
   limit.
4. Support asynchronous writing.
5. Supports x86_64.

I make search, and found this libs:

1. Google glog
2. log4cxx
3. log4cplus
4. log4cpp
5. rlog
6. Pantheios

But none of them supports all of what I need. And for example `rlog` has a very poor documentation, from which I can't make my decision.

Maybe you can help me to find logging library?

Comment: Unless you write your own library you won't find one that fulfills all your requirements. Besides most of those requirements shoud be supported by most of those. If your expecting a list of possible solutions you should ask in Chat we don't do product recomendations here at Superuser.  Besides this has been asked and answered in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692238/better-logging-library-for-c?rq=1

Comment: What about [boost-log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) ?

Comment: Dirk Eddelbuettel, I've problems with compiling this library on my server, so I can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback a log file? nothing will support that. 
The log4xxx ones will alllow you to write rolling log files - so when one reaches a certain size (or time, daily for example) it will start a new file.

The log4 ones are pretty standard and are really rather good, the performance of log4net trashed the Microsoft logging block for example, and as they support all the other languages it makes them a sort-of standard IMHO.

Comment: Yes log4xxx suppors rolling log files, but I can't use both of this features (reach some size or time) together.

Comment: the benefit of open source: [add the option to the project](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)