# Fastest way to make console output "verbose" or not

Tags: c++

I am making a small system and I want to be able to toggle "verbose" text output in the whole system.

I have made a file called globals.h:

```
namespace REBr{
    extern bool console_verbose = false;
}
```

If this is true I want all my classes to print a message to the console when they are constructing, destructing, copying or doing pretty much anything.

For example:

```
window(string title="",int width=1280,int height=720):
Width(width),Height(height),title(title)
{
    if(console_verbose){
        std::cout<<"Generating window #"<<this->instanceCounter;
        std::cout<<"-";
    }
    this->window=SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),0,0,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(console_verbose)
        std::cout<<"-";
    if(this->window)
    {
        this->glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
        if(console_verbose)
            std::cout<<".";
        if(this->glcontext==NULL)
        {
            std::cout<<"FATAL ERROR IN REBr::WINDOW::CONSTR_OPENGLCONTEXT: "<<SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    else std::cout<<"FATAL ERROR IN REBr::WINDOW::CONSTR_WINDOW: "<<SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;
    if(console_verbose)
        std::cout<<">done!"<<endl;
}
```

Now as you can see I have a lot of ifs in that constructor. And I REALLY dont want that since that will slow down my application. I need this to be as fast as possible without removing the "loading bar" (this helps me determine at which function the program stopped functioning).

What is the best/fastest way to accomplish this?

---

Everying in my system is under the namespace REBr

Comment: Mark `console_verbose` as `constexpr`. It apparently will cause compiler to optimize all `if`s if their expressions are evaluated as `false`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to avoid typing `if(...)` every time, just define a macro `#define VERB_STREAM if(console_verbose) std::cout ` and use it like `VERB_STREAM << "Generating window #" << this->instanceCounter << '-';`

Comment: you should also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6692238/1632887

Comment: "And I REALLY don't want that since that will slow down my application": this is absolutely unavoidable (unless you make the feature compile-time enabled/disabled): there must be a test on the verbose flag somewhere. By the way, there is no reason to avoid it as the time overhead is quite neglectible.

Comment: Alexey and @chtz Thanks for the really useful advice! This will definately become useful in my program. I think I will go for a define or logger class (like Bruce mentioned) but add your stuff in to make it faster.

Comment: @Alexey how will I set the variable if its a constexpr. It can only be initialized immediately. The variable is in a global namespace so it will be initialized before the main is even called. How will I change the flag?

Comment: @MoustacheSpy do you mean, that you want to change the flag in runtime and, at the same time, throwing out these `if`s? It isn't possible after the program has been compiled.

Comment: @Alexey I actually wanted it to be changeable once when initializing the whole system. But I think its fine if I leave it in my globals.h. Thanks! Please add your comment as a answer so I can tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variants to achieve that:

1. Use some logger library. It is the best option as it gives you maximum flexibility and some useful experience ;) And you haven't to devise something. For example, look at Google [GLOG](https://github.com/google/glog).
2. Define some macro, allowing you to turn on/off all these logs by changing only the macro. But it isn't so easy to write such marco correctly.
3. Mark your conditional flag as constexpr. That way you may switch the flag and, depending on its value, compiler will optimise `if`s in compiled program. But `if`s will still be in code, so it looks kinda bulky.

Anyway, all these options require program recompilation. W/o recompilation it is impossible to achieve the maximum speed.

Comment: Very informative, very detailed and includes multiple answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often use a Logger class that supports debug levels.  A call might look like:

```
logger->Log(debugLevel, "%s %s %d %d", timestamp, msg, value1, value2);
```

The Logger class supports multiple debug levels so that I can fine tune the debug output. This can be set at any time through the command line or with a debugger.  The Log statement uses a variable length argument list much like printf.

Comment: How exactly do you instanciate this class? Are you making an instance for every function you want to use it in or are you making a global instance. And if so why not just make some functions and variables inside a namespace?

Comment: @MoustacheSpy: I instantiate a global instance in my main routine so that startup is predictable.  Since my applications are almost completely object-oriented, I use classes/methods over functions, but that is somewhat arbitrary, beyond the obvious advantage of encapsulation.  Also, if multiple threads are accessing the logs, you want thread-safe protection.  The class can use thread-safe and non-thread-safe calls using polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

[Google's logging module](https://github.com/google/glog) is widely used in the industry and supports logging levels that you can set from the command line.  For example (taken from their documentation)

```
VLOG(1) << "I'm printed when you run the program with --v=1 or higher";
VLOG(2) << "I'm printed when you run the program with --v=2 or higher";
```

You can find the code here https://github.com/google/glog and the documentation in the `doc/` folder.